# Oracle - Update a view once a day and overwrite the data when update

Tags: oracle, view

I have this view that is below.

How could I set it to only update once a day and when it is updated, this data should be overwritten

```
CREATE view VW_InformacaoApontamanto as

select *

from INFO_APONTAMENTO as InfoApontamento
INNER JOIN Barco as barco on barco.Id = InfoApontamento.Barco_Id
INNER JOIN LOCAL_OPERACAO as localDaOperacao on localDaOperacao.Id = InfoApontamento.LocalDaOperacao_Id
INNER JOIN CODIGOS_OPERACAO as codigosDeOperacao on codigosDeOperacao.Id = InfoApontamento.CodigosDeOperacao_Id
LEFT JOIN INFO_METEOROLOGICA as infoMetereologica on infoMetereologica.Id = InfoApontamento.InfoMeterologica_Id
LEFT JOIN SUB_CODE_OPERACAO as subCodigosOperacao on subCodigosOperacao.Id = InfoApontamento.SubCodigosDeOperacao_Id
LEFT JOIN INFO_POSICIONAMENTO as infoPosicionamento on infoPosicionamento.Id = InfoApontamento.InfoPosicionamento_Id
```

Comment: A view is just a stored query.  If you want the data to be materialized daily, you likely want a materialized view instead that is set to refresh on whatever schedule you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't, not with a view. It is just a stored query and it doesn't actually contain any data. Whenever tables' contents changes, view contents immediately reflects those changes.

What you're looking for might be a **materialized view** which can be scheduled to refresh e.g. once a day.